# Does the Extended Euclidean Algorithm hold for the case ax - by = c?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While solving the monkey problem, I encountered a problem that require solving this equation:
$$ax - by = c$$
And I was confused when $b < 0$. Does it hold for EEA or this require another special case?

Thanks,
Chan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[YES! Read about it here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)